# Как передать массив методу и индексировать внутри него?

Tags: c#

Как передать массив методу и индексировать внутри него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Method1(int[] array)
{
    foreach (int number in array)
    {
        // Doing something with number ...
    }
}

public void Method2()
{
    Method1(new int[] { 1, 2 });
}
```